# Combining regex in jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I have this jQuery code which replaces some HTML character codes with their equivalent:

```
$('.someText').html()
              .replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
              .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
              .replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
```

That works and all, but is there a way to combine those replace operations all into one regex to make the code more concise?

I'm still wrapping my head around regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has a solution that is more flexible, in case you ever expand beyond just the basic three entities:

[Converting sanitised html back to displayable html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248849/converting-sanitised-html-back-to-displayable-html)

Comment: Thanks for the find, Domenic!  That will come in very handy

Comment: well, at least it solved the problem. But it did not answer the question asked. :D

Answer (score 2):

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929264/is-there-a-more-concise-regular-expression-to-accomplish-this-task/2929343#2929343) a while ago. Simple answer; there may be a way to do it, but it's probably better to do what you have here. Each replacement is it's own operation, so might as well leave it that way.