# VB.NET Regex Boolean Match

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am score a password based on various features, but I don't believe my RegEx is correct:

```
    If Regex.IsMatch(password, "/\d+/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) Then
        'Contains a number
        score += 1
    End If

    If Regex.IsMatch(password, "/[a-z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) Then
        'Contains a lowercase letter
        score += 1
    End If

    If Regex.IsMatch(password, "/[A-Z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) Then
        'Contains an uppercase letter
        score += 1
    End If

    If Regex.IsMatch(password, "/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) Then
        'Contains special character
        score += 2
    End If
```

How do I fix this? I believe these are formatted for C# not VB.NET.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I don't believe this is working correctly. I was hoping someone could help me improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Net Regex class takes the raw text of the regular expression.

You should not wrap it in `/` characters; those simply match the literal text `/`.

Some other notes:

- You don't need `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`
- Character classes are not comma-separated
- You're missing a *large* number of special characters.  Use a negated class (all non-alphanumeric chars)
- You can make them faster by pre-compiling them into reusable `Regex` instances instead of re-parsing each regex every time.

Comment: Code example please? Also, is the IsMatch method correct or should it be just Match?

Comment: So all I would need for number is `"\d"` as the pattern to match?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929264/is-there-a-more-concise-regular-expression-to-accomplish-this-task